# How can I remove a (down)vote that I accidentaly made

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, moderation, ethics

I noticed that I have accidentally casted a down-vote, and now it is locked for removal.

I noticed this by my reputation gain not being equal to a multiple of 5 and when I looked it up (I thought somebody gave *me* a down-vote) I found out that this down-vote must have occurred accidentally while browsing on the small touchscreen of my phone.

This happened before and in that case I made some cosmetic edit to the post and removed the vote. This does not really seem like a good option especially when the answer/question is fine.

**Is there a better way to remove a locked vote?**

Comment: Waiting for the post to be edited is your only option

Comment: There is no way to flag it or notify moderators about it? Or otherwise what about the ethics of making a small edit to the post to be able to remove the vote?

Comment: No, mods can't touch up/ down or accept votes.

Comment: Just favorite the question. You can then sort on activity in the favorites tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, unless the post you voted for was edited.

You have to consider a few things: a single downvote 'costs' the author 2 reputation points. It is not such a big deal. If you really feel bad about it, and the post can benefit from an edit, you could do the following:

- Edit the post to improve the quality (not just to edit it to unlock your vote!);
- If you only can suggest edits right now, you have to wait until the suggested edit gets approved. You will see a +2 on your own reputation;
- If the post was successfully edited, you can undo or reverse your downvote.

You shouldn't flag your post for moderator attention. Moderators are not to undo your voting mistakes and can't change your votes.

Comment: I understand, but one single vote is often not significant enough.